# List Manipulation of Duplicates

Tags: python, string, list, function, count

So I have elements in a list that I would like to manipulate, basically I want this to happen:

```
input:
my_list = ['Gold Trophy (January)', 'Gold Trophy (February)', 'Bronze Trophy 
(March)']

output:
['Gold Trophy x2', 'Bronze Trophy (March)']
```

When there is a duplicate common string (such as in the case of Gold Trophy), I want both of those elements deleted, and a new element formed that says (Gold Trophy x(amount of duplicates))

Here's what I have so far:

```
my_list = ['Gold Trophy (January)', 'Gold Trophy (February)', 'Bronze Trophy 
(March)']

# function to count how many duplicates
def countX(my_list, myString): 
    count = 0
    for ele in my_list: 
        if (myString in ele): 
            count = count + 1
    return count 

myString = 'Gold Trophy'
real_count = (countX(my_list, myString))


print(*my_list, sep=', ')
print('duplicates = '+str(countX(my_list, myString)))
```

At this point, this code runs and returns how many duplicates of the specified string are in the list. Any ideas on where to from here to achieve the desired output? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without using the regex. I have put the comments for clarity on what is happening.

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = ['Gold Trophy (January)', 'Gold Trophy (February)', 'Bronze Trophy (March)']
output_ls = []
trophy_ls = []
month_ls = []
trophy_cnt_dc = {}
for item in my_list:
    trophy_ls.append(item.split(' (')[0])
    month_ls.append(item.split(' (')[1])
# print(trophy_ls) >> ['Gold Trophy', 'Gold Trophy', 'Bronze Trophy']
# print(month_ls) >> ['January)', 'February)', 'March)']
trophy_cnt_dc = dict(Counter(trophy_ls))
#print(trophy_cnt_dc) >> {'Gold Trophy': 2, 'Bronze Trophy': 1}
for k,v in trophy_cnt_dc.items():
    if v > 1:
        output_ls.append(k+' x'+str(v))
    else:
        ind = trophy_ls.index(k)
        output_ls.append(k+' ('+month_ls[ind])
print(output_ls)
```

Output:

```
['Gold Trophy x2', 'Bronze Trophy (March)']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution (see comments for clarification). Note that I used a little hack for splitting names and dates: I split on `(` and then restore it if needed. It's possible to do it cleaner, but it's unclear if it's required.

```
my_list = ['Gold Trophy (January)', 'Gold Trophy (February)', 'Bronze Trophy (March)']

# Create map of tuples: (name, date)
pairs = [tuple(x.split('(')) for x in my_list]

# count the number of each name
counts = dict()
for (name, day) in pairs:
    counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

# create a dictionary from initial list
# it doesn't matter how collisions are resolved
# the dictionary is required to process each name only once
init = dict(pairs)
res = []

# for each name:
#   if count is > 1, print the count
#   if count is 1, then print its date
for (name, date) in init.items():
    if counts[name] > 1:
        res.append(name + 'x' + str(counts[name]))
    else:
        res.append(name + '(' + date)
print(res)
```